# Grails domain class constraints for relation between fields

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-validation

I need to write Domain class constraint in Grails which says that one integer field must be greater or equal than the other.

When I write the code like this:

```
class MyDomain {

 String title
 int valueMin = 1
 int valueMax = 1

 static constraints = {
  valueMin(min:1)
  valueMax(min:valueMin)
 }
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: valueMin for class: MyDomain
```

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html

This should more or less work (not tested)

```
class MyDomain {

 String title
 int valueMin = 1
 int valueMax = 1

 static constraints = {
  valueMin(min:1)
  valueMax(validator:{
    value, reference ->
    return value > reference.valueMin
  })
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This wont work, because the constraints are a static block of code which will only have access to static variables.

So, you could write your own customized cosntraint if you want: take a look at this link: 
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#7. Validation